# Telerik gird Edit pop-up - Unable to save the changes when one of the field is updated using jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Environment Telerik grid (2019.2.619.545), Ajax binding, popup edit mode, when I click on the edit button on a row grid is displaying the edit popup window.
when I change one of the text box value using jquery ( i am not typing the value in the textbox) and then click on save is not saving the changes to the server.
When I change the value using jquery I can see the value changed, however, grid edit window is not saving that change. Why is this happening please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is not marked dirty. Changing the text box in your HTML does not inform kendo ui about this change.

That's why your change is not persisted. You have to update your model. Like this:

```js
// use the "set" method to inform MVVM of the changes
dataItem.set("property", value);
```

Or set the text box value via its api:

```js
$("#textbox").val(value).change();
```